# ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION skips row number 1 occasionaly

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, row-number

I have an SQL Query like this:

```
SELECT [a].*,
       [rp].[TestId],
       [r].[Deleted]
FROM (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [RollId] ORDER BY [TimeStamp] DESC) AS row
      FROM [RollAction]) a
     INNER JOIN [RollPermission] rp ON ([rp].[RoId] = [a].[RollId]
                                    AND [rp].[RoType] = [a].[RoType]
                                    AND [rp].[UserId] = [a].[UserId]
                                    AND [rp].[Deleted] = 0)
     INNER JOIN [Roll] r ON ([r].[Id] = [a].[RollId]
                         AND [r].[RoType] = [a].[RollType]
                         AND [r].[Deleted] = 0)
WHERE row = 1
  AND [a].[Action] = 'Fetched'
  AND [a].[RollType] = 'Test'
  AND [a].[Deleted] = 0
  AND [a].[UserId] = 5
ORDER BY [a].[TimeStamp] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

What i want to accomplish: `Fetch` the first 3 rows from `RollAction` `inner join` filtered by `RollPermission` and `Roll like` the `inner joins` that I've done.

It works, but it skips one partition, so it does fetch the first,third and fourth row. Because one partition doesn't have row 1 and 2 for some reason, so it gets filtered away in the `WHERE` Clause.

Why does that partition skip rows? I've tried to take away all Where clauses but it still skips, i tried to take away the innerjoins too.

My question is how do i force it to not skip row number 1 and 2, or exchange row = 1 to select the lowest row number that exists in each partition

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I'm not sure what you mean by "skips one partition".

Comment: The partitions are grouped by RollId with unique row numbers starting from 1, but in one partition the row number 1 and 2 is skipped, so it gets filtered away in the where clause because i set it to row=1. My question is how do i force it to not skip row number 1 and 2, or exchange row = 1 to select the lowest row number that exists in each partition

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't provide sample data..

Comment: Why not, @LittleMygler ? `ROW_NUMBER`, will always generate a row "1" for every group in the partition, and will generate each number in the order defined. It will never skip a number. if the numbers aren't in your results, it's because you've filtered them out after generating them. We really need a way to replicate the problem; and that *will* need sample data.

Comment: Like most of us here, you can't provide _actual_ data, but with some effort you can certainly provide _sample_ data. The idea is to provide a data set that reproduces your problem that others can work with to help you solve said problem. If you try to answer this question, [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), odds are good that you'll also answer your own question.

Comment: Move `AND [a].[Action] = 'Fetched' AND [a].[RollType] = 'Test' AND [a].[Deleted] = 0 AND [a].[UserId] = 5` inside the subquery. The `ROW_NUMBER()` could be 1 with `UserId <> 5`

Comment: THANKS YOU XANATOS! Can you make it an actual answer? I mean so i can accept it as the answer to my issue and upvote :)

Comment: Hope you got fix moving `Where` clause into `sub-query`. Don't you think your `INNER JOINS` also may give same problem (in future), in case, join criteria fails with any one of row which got `ROW_NUMBER ()` already in sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer came from Xanatos.

Move `AND [a].[Action] = 'Fetched' AND [a].[RollType] = 'Test' AND [a].[Deleted] = 0 AND [a].[UserId] = 5` inside the subquery

Answer (score -1):

RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER might be a possibilty

Comment: It also give the first row in the same partition row number 3 instead of 1

Comment: Can it be that someone had deleted a row in the database, that it still thinks that they exist?